# Trying to install CUDA, but getting errors

Tags: drivers, nvidia, cuda

I have tried a number of solutions suggested here and only when I try to install `cuda`. But I keep getting the following errors when I do the following

```
sudo apt install -y cuda
```

Errors were encountered while processing:

```
 nvidia-dkms-450
 nvidia-driver-450
 cuda-drivers-450
 cuda-drivers
 cuda-runtime-11-0
 cuda-11-0
 cuda-demo-suite-11-0
 cuda
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

This is for Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: Please edit your question and include the whole unredacted output.  Are you running `sudo apt update` before other commands in `apt`? Is all of your software up-to-date before attempting to install new software?

Comment: The i386 package is only necessary for systems using 32 bit architecture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to download the drivers first. Try first running this

```
sudo apt install libnvidia-tesla-cuda1 libnvidia-tesla-cuda1-i386
```

then running your install command when Apt is finished with this one.

This is the description from `apt search` :

> NVIDIA CUDA Driver Library (Tesla version)

**EDIT**

After doing more research on the question, I found the official documentation which includes installation instructions. As it turns out, there is a bit more to the process:

###### Perform the pre-installation actions.

Install repository meta-data

```
    $ sudo dpkg -i cuda-repo-<distro>_<version>_<architecture>.deb
```

Install the CUDA public GPG key

When installing using the local repo:

```
    $ sudo apt-key add /var/cuda-repo-<distro>-<version>/7fa2af80.pub
```

When installing using network repo on Ubuntu 20.04/18.04:

```
    $ sudo apt-key adv --fetch-keys https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/<distro>/<architecture>/7fa2af80.pub
```

When installing using network repo on Ubuntu 16.04:

```
    $ sudo apt-key adv --fetch-keys http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/<distro>/<architecture>/7fa2af80.pub
```

Pin file to prioritize CUDA repository:

```
    $ wget https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/<distro>/<architecture>/cuda-<distro>.pin
    $ sudo mv cuda-<distro>.pin /etc/apt/preferences.d/cuda-repository-pin-600
```

Update the Apt repository cache

```
    $ sudo apt-get update
```

Install CUDA
Note: These two commands must be executed separately.

```
    $ sudo apt-get install cuda
```

To include all GDS packages:

```
    $ sudo apt-get install nvidia-gds
```

Perform the post-installation actions.

**SOURCES**

[Official Installation Guide](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html)

[Section on Apt based install on Ubuntu](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html)